# sub report to main report value passing in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I want to get sub report to main report value pass. How this possible?

[this is my main report and My Need format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgZvc.png)

And sub report is-
[this is my Sub report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK1PP.png)

**AVGQty** formula is - `Sum ({Command.IssueQty})/Sum ({Command.WorkingDays})`

I want to get every Item Wise average from sub report in main report using report link.

as like, Acetic Acid - **AVG Qty: 128.91** (Item wise value come from sub report)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a shared `numbervar` in your formula.

In your case:

```
shared numbervar AVGQty:= Sum ({Command.IssueQty})/Sum ({Command.WorkingDays});
```

then in your `main report` you simply create a `formula` with:

```
shared numbervar AVGQty
```

Comment: I just edited the answer, please address @Rui Rita about the answer.

Comment: Hey, @Rui Rita, plz do something about this. Sorry, this way don't work.

Comment: Hi @Imrul Kaesh, you can call your sub-report in your category section, but within the sub-report don't show the values, let them be suppressed because you just need the avg values.  The only thing you will show in your sub-report (in the report footer) is the avg formula

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you don't need callback value (shared variables) from subreport in your main report. Just include subreport dataset into your main report and link those 2 tables in database expert.

So for example you have `table a` which is in your **main report** and `table b` which is you **subreport**. You link them from `itemname` from table a to `itemname` to table b. To make this without any shared variables you should just add table b to main report, in database expert link both tables with itemname and then you can group by attribute itemname from table a to get summarizes which you want.

You can do it with shared variables or with this logic. Your choice

Hope it helps